# Comparing falsy values in Python

Tags: python

Why does the expression below evaluate to False? Both the values in the comparison are [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```py
print('' == [])
```

Comment: they may be empty, but they are different types. one is a string and the other is a list, and therefore are not equivalent to each other

Comment: Python is different from js! Try `print(bool('') == bool([]))`

Comment: They don't both evaluate to False in the sense you are using. Consider: `[] == False` or `'' == False`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> An object’s **type** determines the operations that the object supports (e.g., “does it have a length?”) and also **defines the possible values** for objects of that type.

Furthermore, [**it**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) also states:

> `==` compares the values of two objects

However, since the value of an object in Python is pretty much abstract, in that there is no canonical method to access it, the default behavior of `==` compares the **[identity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)** of the two objects (which can be thought of as the object’s address in memory) but is defined as:

> An integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same identity.

*It's also important to mention that many built-in types have customized comparison methods within their respective types that compare based on their 'values'.*

While it's true that both of your objects are Falsy, they are of different types (String and List), and as a result, the default behavior of comparing identities is used. Since there is no chance of the two objects having non-overlapping lifetimes, their identities will be different, and so `'' == []` will evaluate to `False`.

In order to compare the Truthy values of two objects, first convert them to booleans as Waket suggested in the comments:

```
bool('') == bool([])
```

taking advantage of Python's **[truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)**.